# Embedding an image stored in github

Tags: html, github

I'm uploading a folder of images for a project to GitHub and I want to display them in Flask.

```
<img src="https://github.com/madelinekinnaird/Gerrymandr/blob/master/images/az1.PNG">
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work. Do I need to use another image storage site, or is it possible to use GitHub for this purpose?

Comment: Try opening that URL in your browser. It takes you to a webpage, not an image file.

Comment: I don't think you should use github as a static files host. This may even violate the TOS

Comment: `<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/madelinekinnaird/Gerrymandr/master/images/az1.PNG">`

Answer (score 21):

Your approach looks correct. However, you are linking to the file *in the github repository*. Instead, you should link to image itself. You can get the link by right clicking on the image and select "copy image address".

In your case the link would be:

https://github.com/madelinekinnaird/Gerrymandr/blob/master/images/az1.PNG?raw=true

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your image are located at

https://github.com/userName/ImageRepo

Than to access that image from a browser use below link
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/userName/ImageRepo/master/FileName.ext

eg:
location: https://github.com/pavanghai/images/blob/master/wine_scatter.jpg

Browser link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pavanghai/images/master/wine_scatter.jpg

Comment: I am creating an android app and thinking to store 300+ images there. I want to ask will GitHub block my app user IP if they send too many requests to access the image?